# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Data Science's [second moderator election](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the three new moderators are:

[image: Dawny33] [image: Stephen Rauch] [image: oW_]

They'll be [the new moderator team](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking Aleksandr Blekh, Sean Owen and Steve Kallestad who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4659866368999424/0).

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations to Dawny33, Stephen Rauch, and oW_!  This is a great team, who will be great for the health of this site!

Comment: Thank you. Will always look up to you for moderation advice though :)

Answer (score 7):

Congrats everyone! Let's have a great, active moderation term. I am sure that those that got elected will do their best. What I truly hope is that the rest will stay active as well and contribute as much as they can.

Answer (score 0):

Looking forward to continuing to see you guys in action around the site in your new roles. Well done!